# How Do I Include a Scaled Variable into a Computation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I'm trying to calculate the fall time of an object that has some gliding properties. Meaning it can convert velocity into lift at a small ratio.

If I am given that lift is a linear function of downward velocity and time, $l = f(x, t)$ and terminal velocity for the object is -320:
$$0 = f(0, 1)$$
$$2 = f(-320, 1)$$
$$4 = f(-320, 2)$$
Given the function for calculating the fall time is $\frac{gt^2}{2} + vt + y = \beta$, and given $g$, $v$, $y$, and $\beta$ I can calculate the time to terminal velocity: [Finding Fall Time With Terminal Velocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1319972/finding-fall-time-with-terminal-velocity)

Which brings me to my question: Can I just add in the result of this function to my fall time calculation prior to terminal velocity? Is this legitimate:
$$\frac{gt^2}{2} + vt + y + f(\frac{gt}{2} + v, t) = \beta$$
I'm not sure if it matters, but my $f$ looks like this:
$$l = \frac{xt}{-160}$$